# I want to add the the raw content which is stored in segment folder nutch version 1.17

Tags: nutch

While running this command below:
bin/nutch solrindex http://localhost:8983/solr/nutch/ testingnewline/crawldb -linkdb testingnewline/linkdb -dir testingnewline/segments/ -deleteGone -addBinaryContent
It is throwing below exception.

```
Error: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/nutch: ERROR: [doc=https://www.saintlukeskc.org/] Error adding field 'binaryContent'
```

May I know what changes need to do I need to change the schema.xml.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The Solr schema must contain the field "binaryContent", see [Nutch's default Solr schema.xml](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/release-1.17/src/plugin/indexer-solr/schema.xml#L424) which contains all the fields eventually added by Nutch or one of the plugins.

Comment: schema.xml <!-- field containing segment's raw binary content if indexed with -addBinaryContent -->
    <field name="binaryContent" type="binary" stored="true" indexed="false"/>

Comment: I have added plugins names are |index-(basic|anchor|more|metadata).
May I know is i am missing anything to addbinarycontent.

Comment: There is no need to add a plugin to send the binary content to Solr (or any other index back-end), the binary content is added as field "binaryContent" by the core indexer. Plugins implementing IndexingFilter do not have access to the binary content. However, Solr needs to know this field and which type of data it contains. In doubt, check the logs of Solr for more details about the error.